# $timeout in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout

In My piece of code , I want to show a certain modal pop up only after a few seconds(5 seconds) of delay once the progress bar shows.

```
myApp.showPleaseWait(); //Shows the progress bar

TransactionApiServices.postUnmergeTransactionResearchDetails(researchParams).success(function (results) {
    console.log("User have access");

    $timeout(myApp.hidePleaseWait(),5000); //Show the bar for 5 seconds and then close it

    getUnmergeResearchPopup($scope, $uibModal, $scope.detailData, $rootScope); //Open the pop up
}).error(function (result) {
```

but the timeout is not working properly . It closes before 5 seconds and shows the pop up. What am I doing wrong ?

I have injected $timeout already though.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$timeout(function() {
    myApp.hidePleaseWait()
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the result of `myApp.hidePleaseWait()` into the `$timeout` rather than the function itself. Try this:

```
$timeout(myApp.hidePleaseWait, 5000);
```